# Does personality insights have language support for hebrew?

Tags: personality-insights

I am using personality insights and I do not see language support for hebrew.  Does personality insights have language support for hebrew? If so, what is the code?  If not, any idea when it will?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for questions about programming -- for questions about future plans for Personality Insights, you should probably contact the company directly.

Comment: Questions about the Watson product roadmap are best asked on https://developer.ibm.com/answers/. Disclosure: I am an evangelist for IBM Watson.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Personality Insights only has support for content in English and Spanish.

We are working on adding more languages currently, but don't have anything we can announce yet.